# sql- server 2008 r2 concat two strings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

`update qtable set Section = Section + ',Teaching' where qid=522`

this update statement doesnot  concat/append the values.

```
  Section contains null value initially.
```

Comment: Please show us sample input data and the output you expect.

Comment: can you describe what you mean by 'doesnot work'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat()` if you are working with SQL Server 2012  instead:

```
update qtable 
set Section = concat(Section, ',Teaching') 
where qid=522;
```

For older version you can use

```
update qtable 
set Section = coalesce(Section, '') + ',Teaching'
where qid=522;
```

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
update qtable set Section = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),ISNULL(Section,'')) + ',Teaching' where qid=522
```